# How do I use normalize.css with npm?

Tags: css, npm

I'm handling my dependencies with `npm`, but until now I used it mainly for Javascript code and I always imported the installed packages in my code with the useful `require()`.

Recently I found that normalize.css could be installed with `npm`.
What are the advantages? How do I use it in my code (both static `.html` and dynamic `.js` files) after installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[parcelify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/parcelify) is really useful for doing just this. You can use it in concert with the [normalize.css](https://www.npmjs.org/package/normalize.css/) package.

JS:

```
require('normalize.css');
```

then run parcelify:

```
$ parcelify main.js -c bundle.css
```

You can add an npm script to your `package.json` so you don't have to install `parcelify` globally to use it in your project:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "your-package",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Your package",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcelify main.js -c bundle.css"
  }
}
```

and then just do:

```
$ npm run build
```

Comment: so in main.js file I `require` my css files and then when passed to parcelify, it will output the `require`d files in bundle.css?

Comment: So long as the modules you `require()` have `style` entries in their `package.json`, they will get bundled.

Comment: Could you setup a small example? I'm not really understanding

Comment: You can have a look at the tests in the `parcelify` repo for some basic examples: https://github.com/rotundasoftware/parcelify/tree/master/test

Comment: I think the answer to "how do I use X?" should not be "by using Y". "Using Y" may be a valid way of "using X" but in this case I dont think it is the direct and default way. No downvote though as I can see how it may solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to PostCSS in your workflow `postcss-import` can be very useful in doing this, allowing you to import both local and installed dependencies through the simple `@import` rule.

Then PostCSS will take care for you to inline the proper stylesheets.

For example, to use normalize.css as in the question:

```
@import "normalize.css";
```

In some main.css you will then link in the HTML.

The only downside to this is you can't explicitly *componentize* your CSS and have it pick the necessary stylesheets just by requiring them from the component's code.